# (Swift) Can't retrieve paths for only video assets

Tags: swift

So I have a very simple call to get the path to a video file in Swift. Assuming the video is named "Video.mp4":

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video", ofType: "mp4") // Returns nil
```

This returns nil, without exception. Same for using URLForResource().

The weird thing is that if have an image file that has been imported the same way (all assets are in the "Copy Bundle Resources" pane), it works perfectly:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Image", ofType: "png") // Returns the correct path
```

Anybody have hunches on what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the name of your file Video?  If it just happens to be a video file but has a different name, then it will return nil.  Either pathForResource or URLForResource should give you the path.  You may have to unwrap the optional.  The only other way to get nil is to not have the file in the resources folder.

Comment: Nope, that all checks out fine. I just tested it on a computer at work (I run a Hackintosh back home) and now everything's working fine. I've never run into any problems like this before, but I'm now willing to suspect the problem is that I'm not on a "real" mac.

Comment: Hmm, this is a conundrum

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too. I finaly solved the problem.

1. Switch iOS Deployment Target to iOS 8

   - Run the app it works!!!
2. Switch iOS Deployment Target back to iOS 9

   - Run the app it works again!!!

A weird problem and a solution :))

I hope it helps.